# Surface area of S, parameterized as $r(u,v)=( 2\cos(u),2\sin(u),v )\;\;,0 ≤ u ≤ 2π, 0 ≤ v ≤2.$

Tags: calculus, parametric

I first found the tangent vectors, $r_{u}$ and $r_{v}$. Then compute $$\lvert r_{u} \ \times \ r_{v}\lvert$$ and I got $$\sqrt{4(\cos^{2}u+\sin^{2}u)}.$$ I simplified it. $$\sqrt{4}=2,$$ because v is the axis of the cylinder, so I figured do I need a double integral to deal with this? $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}2dvdu?$$ Is this correct?

Comment: Tmm: I edited/formatted your post a wee bit.  Please let me know if what you see in your posted question is okay with you.

Comment: @amWhy thanks! looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a better (more general) way of solving this using the First Fundamental Form of differential geometry:

$$(I_{kl}(u,v)) = \begin{pmatrix} E(u,v) & F(u,v) \\ F(u,v) & G(u,v) \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} g_{11}(u,v) & g_{12}(u,v) \\ g_{21}(u,v) & g_{22}(u,v) \end{pmatrix}$$

and then apply the following:

$$A(\Omega) = \iint_\Omega \sqrt{EG-F^2} dudv$$

Using this approach you can solve the areas of more complex surfaces!

EDIT:

Following what you were doing we get
$$A = \int_0^{2\pi}du\int_0^2dv \lVert r_u \times r_v\rVert = \int_0^{2\pi}du\int_0^2dv \sqrt{4(cos^2u + sin^2u)} = \int_0^{2\pi}du\int_0^2dv \ 2 $$
where we used the trigonometric equality $cos^2u + sin^2u  = 1$.

To me this would be an easier way than trying to change to polars as the integrals in the cartesian form can be solved without any issues.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly broadening my horizon. Nevertheless, this is related to my study in Calculus, would you please do me a favor by showing me if my calculus approach is working? or some mistakes exist?

Comment: Hi! Im not very convinced on why you tried to use polar parametrization. You had already calculated the normal vector of that surface, so half of the job is done. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: can't wait to see it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your double integral looks OK.

Since you are extruding a circle radius $2$  to form a cylinder of length/height $=2$.

A short way to find area by Pappu's theorem is

$$ 2 \cdot \pi\cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 8 \pi $$